# Too many 'Total Connections'. Is it normal status? MaxScale 2.3.9

Tags: mariadb, maxscale

I installed **Mariadb 10.3.15** and **Maxscale 2.3.9**
It works fine, but sometimes the query speed is slow.

When I look at the status of the service through `MaxCtrl`, I can see that the value of 'Total Connections' is very high. At first it was small, but the value is still increasing, is this normal state value?

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 0):

What is the limit of connections from MaxScale?  From the clients?  What kind of clients -- web servers or what?

My point is that it not MariaDB's problem, it is something upstream.

If "query speed is slow", that sounds like a poorly indexed table or a poorly written query.  Set `long_query_time=1` and turn on the slowlog.

Comment: Maxscale's max_connections value is 0(no limit)
Client is Hive Metastore(using Hortonworks Data Platform 3.0)
hive metasotre throws out a huge number of SELECT queries.

Comment: @AIWeaver - Is that "total connections"?  Or "concurrent connections"?  Crank it down to 50 concurrent connections and see how that feels.

Answer (score 0):

`Total Connections` displays the total number of connections made to backends **since maxscale start**. It is normal it grows as every new connection established is counted.

`Connections` are the **currently connections established** to your backends, active (serving queries) + idle. Your backends should be able to handle these (hardware + network + configuration), otherwise it can slowdown things.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-maxctrl/#list-services